# Removing Firebase Data by key that's stored in different dictionaries

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

In my app I have a few table views to show user specific data.
To display the data I use FIRDAtabaseQuery. And when a user deletes the row from a specific table view, depending on the query only certain data gets deleted.

When a user saves their data it gets stored in two places "topics" "and user-posts" as shown below

```
topics
    -KTUMSoVFjN8tR82KUPl
        author: 
        "Joshua Browne"
        body: 
       "Notes:"

user-posts       
       x0MJQL0vRMZXZ83ouI8EvUVaPPd2addclose
       -KTUMSoVFjN8tR82KUPl
        author: 
        "Joshua Browne"
        body: 
        "Notes:"
```

As you can see they both have the same key.
A user can delete a row  with the code below and depending on whether I have queried "topics" or "user-posts" only one will be deleted.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {

        [[self refForIndex: indexPath.row] removeValue];
    }
}
```

So my question is, in the code where i state: 
 `[[self refForIndex:indexPath.row] removeValue];`

Is there a way I can tell the code than when a key from one of the directories is removed, if that same key is present in another directory, also remove that reference.

Right now I query the data from user-posts as follows:

```
-(FIRDatabaseQuery *)getQuery {

    return [[self.ref child:@"user-posts"] child:[super getUid]];
}
```

And if I remove the value it is deleted permanently which is what I want.

If I were to change the query to:

```
- (FIRDatabaseQuery *) getQuery {

    FIRDatabaseQuery *recentPostsQuery = [[self.ref child:@"topics"] queryLimitedToFirst:100];
    return recentPostsQuery;
}
```

I can then remove the value from the topic list permanently when the user deleted the row in the table view. I just cant get it to do both at the same time.

Comment: Can you clean up that last paragraph a bit?  Is the question, how to determine if the key of the item removed from one dictionary is present in the other?

Comment: Yes and then if so, also remove that reference.